# local vs global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, global-variables

I have this code in Javascript:

```
var words = [];

d3.json("myFile.json", function(data) {
    words = data.words;
    console.log(words);  //Log output to console
});

console.log(words);  //Log output to console
```

The first `console.log(words);` shows an array of seven objects.
But the second `console.log(words);` shows an empty array. So it looks like `words` outside of the `d3.json` function is not the same as `words` inside that function.

I also have tried to use `console.log(window.words);` outside of the function and it still shows an empty array.

How can I get the data that I have read from `myFile.json` in the `d3.json` function, outside of that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.json` is an *asynchronous* function. That means that the code you pass is not executed immediately, but as a *callback* after the request for the JSON file returns. That is, a network request is sent for the file, but the normal flow of execution continues.

The `console.log(words);` outside `d3.json` is simply executed before the call returns and the array is populated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way I can wait until the array populated and then use it?

Comment: I tried to delay the second `console.log(words);` by adding:       `var aa;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
 aa= 10 + Math.random() * 90;
}` before that but it didn't help!

Comment: You can use [queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue), move you code into `d3.json` call or call a function and pass `words` to from inside the `d3.json` function.  In addition to Lars comments [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js) might also help.

Comment: @user1614080 thanks for the comment, I did that and it worked, i.e I moved my code inside `d3.json` function.