# d3 csv readin to objects in array

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am currently trying to use the d3 framework for a university visualisation approach.
For testing purpose I want to read a csv-file and parse the rows to objects inside an array.

My csv looks like:

```
 ID, Referred To, TimeStamp, Votes, Comment
```

So I want to read it with the following lines:

```
d3.csv("test_comments.csv", function(data) {
  commentlist = data.map(function(d) {
    return[+d["ID"],
           +d["Referred To"],
           +d["TimeStamp"],
           +d["Votes"],
           +d["Comment"]
          ]
  });
});
```

But if I want to readout the values afterwards I am just getting "undefined"
I also tried the way mbostock described in this thread:
[csv to array in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js)

but working with a global variable is not working either.

```
var commentlist;
d3.csv("test_comments.csv", function(data) {
  commentlist = data.map(function(d) {
    return[+d["ID"],
           +d["Referred To"],
           +d["TimeStamp"],
           +d["Votes"],
           +d["Comment"]
          ]
  });
});
console.log(commentlist);
```

Am I understanding something wrong?
Maybe you have a solution for me.

Comment: Do you have spaces in your CSV like in the headers? Then remove those. Also I'm guessing converting "comment" to a number doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes but just in the comment section, the Idea is a new visualisation of social network comments. So I wanted to store the comments inside of a csv, isnt that possible ?

Comment: Sure, but your code is converting everything in the CSV into numbers, which doesn't make sense if you have strings in there.

Comment: OkayI understand, which char do I have to use to convert to Strings?

Comment: You're getting strings already, no need to convert.

Comment: Okay but I still get undefined as return when trying to print commentlist

Comment: Could be that your CSV isn't loaded correctly. Have you tried the `d3.csv(url, function(error, data) { ... })` version and checking `error`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var commentlist=[];
d3.csv("test_comments.csv", function(data) {
  commentlist=data;
});
console.log(commentlist);
```

What I know is, In the call back data object will contain array of JSON objects of csv file's all rows of data, that each row data is pushed as a JSON format into the data array.
As below

```
[{"ID": valueFromtheRow, "Referred To": value, "TimeStamp": value, "Votes":value, "Comment":value}]
```

The call back function is called by passing the array of JSONs.
So data object will look like

```
data=[{"ID": valueFromtheRow, "Referred To": value, "TimeStamp": value, "Votes":value, "Comment":value}];
```

Hope you understood...If not ask me.

Comment: Thanks that is another try, but I want to access for instance console.log(commentlist[1]) I get undefined as return.

Comment: @hGen CSV function in d3 is asynchronous, commentlist[1] is undefined, probably the csv file is not loaded yet and data in csv file is yet to be assigned to commentlist variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you got { console.log(commentlist) } undefined is that inside d3.csv the callback function is parsed and called last by browser, and { console.log(commentlist) } is called earlier even though it appears at the bottom of your code. So the moment when { console.log(commentlist) } is called, { commentlist } is actually undefined (only declared).
That being said, just try putting { console.log(commentlist) } inside the callback and it should do the job.

Comment: I had this problem, too. But outside d3.csv I need the "commentlist"-variable for other usage. Is there a possibility to run the d3.csv before another function?