# javascript d3 visualization doesn't load/appear until clicking HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have a d3 app with one HTML number input.  Everything works as I want it to for the moment, except that the visualization doesn't appear in the browser until I actually click the number input up or down.

I tried setting the input with a value:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="5" id="nMinutes">
```

I also tried this workaround:

```
var hack = document.getElementById("nMinutes");
hack.value = "22";
```

to no avail.

I am following this example: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/04/using-html-inputs-with-d3js.html

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/btsusu6v/3/
Note: I am using d3.csv in my actual app:

```
var dataset2
    d3.csv("/assets/csv/mydata.csv", function(d) {
    dataset2=d;
})
```

This is my first venture into D3 (and javascript for that matter), so all general recommendations about the app (and not 100% specific to the posted question) are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The visualization seems to get initialized on input.

```
d3.select("#nMinutes").on("input", function () {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    buildhist(dataset2, +this.value);
});
```

So only once you click on the arrow does your code draw the graphs. If you were to put:

```
buildhist(dataset2, 1);
```

at the end of the JavaScript file, it should work as you intended.

Comment: this definitely works for the fiddle which I simplified too much as it turns out.

I found the solution after reviewing this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js

I had to include the `buildhist(dataset2, 5)` inside the `d3.csv` function.  Like so:

`var dataset2 =
    d3.csv("/assets/csv/cleanTrips.csv", function(d) {
        dataset2=d;
        buildhist(dataset2, 5);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

So I over-simplified the fiddle example, but realized from jstkim7's answer where the issue must lie.  I found the solution after reviewing this post:[csv to array in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js)

I had to include the `buildhist(dataset2, 5)` inside the `d3.csv` function.  Like so:

`var dataset2 =
    d3.csv("/assets/csv/cleanTrips.csv", function(d) {
        dataset2=d;
        buildhist(dataset2, 5);
    });`