# how to open a local file in mozilla firefox using only HTML?

Tags: html, firefox

I am trying to open a file which is on the local disk on firefox using html on a ubuntu machine. But, I am facing file not found error.
My code is as follows:

```
    <body>
        <a href="/home/abc/workspace/logfile.log">LOG FILE</a>
    </body>
```

I tried using file:/// but still the file is not getting opened.

Comment: You could change your file so its formatted in javascript and open it with <script src='myfile.js'></script> or maybe fire-up a local webserver to host the files: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977972/how-do-i-setup-a-local-http-server-using-python**

Answer (score 12):

Use the `file:///` protocol:

```
file:///home/abc/workspace/logfile.log
```

It does not work however for security reasons in a general case. You can disable the security check by editing `about:config`, or by using an extension, however I would not recommend it.

This is the `about:config` key:

```
security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy
```

It is `true` by default, you can set it to `false`.

Comment: Unfortunately this was not enough for me (using firefox from apt, not snap version). "Access to the file was denied" "The file at ___ is not readable"

Answer (score -3):

You cannot access file system using the browser. For obvious security reasons.

Comment: I have numerous HTML documents on my local disk. I am the file owner and can view/edit/delete them using other tools. I do not understand why mozilla deems it insecure to render them for me when I explicitly type the file:/// URL into the browser.