# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 with CoinIMP keys

Tags: java, html, hash, handshake

I saw a lot of post related to this error but looks like the solution is related to the code itself.

I'm trying to do a prevision to the mining of a bitcoin for my thesis and I receive this error during the .start(). Here is my code which is really easy:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Crypto Miner </title>
    <script src="https://www.hostingcloud.racing/8Xr1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Crypto Mining Website</h1>
    <button onclick="startminer()"> Start </button>
    <button onclick="stopminer()"> Stop </button>
    <h1 id="hashes"></h1>
    <script>
        var miner = new Client.Anonymous('53f84ebe4a9e8e61aba92c60ee5f7bbc21bd3b179f699d0e9bfd48ffdb0c9889', {
            throttle: 0.3, c: 'w', ads: 0
            //throttle is to limit maximum CPU usage. In our case is 70%
            //It create a miner object. Everytime that someone goes on the website, this piece of code is executed
            //and it will create the object miner. We put the API key (??) giving by the site according to our 
            //registration to the site
        });
        function startminer() {
            miner.start();
        }
        function stopminer() {
            miner.stop();
        }
        setInterval(function() {
            var hashesPerSecond = miner.getHashesPerSecond();
            var totalHashes = miner.getTotalHashes();
            var acceptedHashes = miner.getAcceptedHashes();

            document.getElementById("hashes").innerHTML = hashesPerSecond;
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
```

Could you explain to my to what is related my error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found this status code in one of the response headers:

```
400 WebSocket connection denied: origin 'file://' not allowed
```

It seems like CoinImp does not give you access to the API if you have a `file:` URL scheme. If you're just double clicking the HTML file that contains your code, it will open up in your browser with the `file:` URL scheme.

Use something like [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986564/6186482) or [Xampp](https://itstillworks.com/use-html-xampp-8604097.html) to host your HTML file on your local machine so that you can access it using `http` or `https`, then CoinImp should stop blocking you.

Comment: Thanks @kyldu I will check your solution using a different platform to start my code

Comment: Thanks @kyldu I solved the problem adding a live server and open the code with it, solving my problem. Your help was very useful!!!