# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when using Object.assign await

Tags: object, d3.js, async-await, assign, observablehq

I am trying to reproduce the grouped bar chart using D3 from [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart). I am running the script on Chrome, with D3.v5.

In the script I have:

```
var data = Object.assign(await d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3887051/raw/805adad40306cedf1a513c252ddd95e7c981885a/data.csv",
    d3.autoType), {
    y: "Population"
});
```

When I ran it in the HTML, it shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I tried it on the Chrome console, it works fine.

HTML file content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 

var data = Object.assign(await d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3887051/raw/805adad40306cedf1a513c252ddd95e7c981885a/data.csv", d3.autoType), {y: "Population"});
 

</script>
```

When successful, data should be a object as the following:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(8), y: "Population"]
```

Comment: I also found this link helpful for me to understand how to do something with data after the async d3.csv (or d3.json) call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js/9492055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to move the code from the [Observable](https://observablehq.com) notebook to a common JavaScript script. In that case, you cannot use `await` like you did.

If you have a look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), you'll see very clearly that:

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used** inside an async function. (emphasis mine)

That being said, this `async` function with your code inside it will work:

```js
(async function foo() {
  const data = Object.assign(await d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3887051/raw/805adad40306cedf1a513c252ddd95e7c981885a/data.csv", d3.autoType), {
    y: "Population"
  });
  console.log(data)
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

That code worked inside an Observable notebook because of the way notebooks work:

> Observable already supported async generators in a sense: you can also define a (synchronous) generator cell that yields promises. Observable waits until the previous promise resolves before pulling the next one from the generator. ([source](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-asynchronous-iteration?collection=@observablehq/introduction))

Finally, regarding your observation that the code worked on Chrome's console: It's not just Chrome, that code will work without the `async` in most modern browsers' console. The explanation is that the code in the console is wrapped in `async` by default. Here is a good reading: https://medium.com/@tomsu/devtools-tips-day-7-the-simple-joys-of-async-console-578f4ce67df4

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just to clarify, isn't d3.csv an async function?  I googled it and found it seems to be asynchronous.  Second questions, I don't understand why it works in the google chrome console, but not the pure javascript.  Can you please shed light on it?

Comment: Yes, it's asynchronous, but that doesn't change how the browser deals with `await`.

Comment: Can you please also help me with the 2nd questions: why await works in google chrome console, but not in the javascript?

Comment: @Frank It's not just Chrome, it works in most browsers' dev tools. This is probably a good read: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes

Comment: @Frank This link is even better, it explains nicely why you don't need the `async` in the console: https://medium.com/@tomsu/devtools-tips-day-7-the-simple-joys-of-async-console-578f4ce67df4. I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Instead of

```
<script>
```